# Why did Serpent die?

Tags: solidity, python, serpent

Was really excited about the prospects of working on Ethereum with its python implementation but learnt that it's getting deprecated...why has this happened and can we hope for any other python wrappers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With regards to *why* Serpent was deprecated, Vitalik recently [Tweeted](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/886400133667201024) that he considers Serpent to be "outdated tech".

The Serpent `README` has been updated in the last couple of days with the following:

> Being a low-level language, Serpent is NOT RECOMMENDED for building
>   applications unless you really really know what you're doing. The
>   creator recommends Solidity as a default choice, LLL if you want
>   close-to-the-metal optimizations, or Viper if you like its features
>   though it is still experimental.

Answer (score 12):

[Vyper](https://github.com/ethereum/viper) is the successor to Serpent. It is under active development, mainly by Vitalik himself.

References:

- [Vyper](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [our security audit](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/serpent-compiler-audit-3095d1257929) for Serpent to see why.

Basically, it's very a bad quality, untested and unmaintained insecure project.

Comment: Why are there no attempts to fix this? Is it because Viper is considered the successor?

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov yes, the project lost momentum and the community is focused on Viper now.