# How to install Serpent and PyEPM on ubuntu

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to install Serpent and PyEPM on ubuntu and I am receiving this error message: "Could not initialize package"

The commands I run:

```
sudo apt-get install Serpent

pip install pyepm
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Nomi - are you following a set of instructions?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to ethereum and Linux, and trying to install the packages according to the instructions here https://github.com/etherex/pyepm and https://github.com/ethereum/serpent. pip already installed on my ubuntu. Are there any packages that I am supposed to install before the installation of  Serpent and PyEPM? thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How to install Serpent and PyEPM on ubuntu

I *wouldn't*.

Both of the repositories you link to in the comments are quite old. I wasn't familiar with `pyepm`, but its repository hasn't been touched in 2 years, and *lots* has happened since then.

More importantly, Vitalik recently voiced his lack of support for Serpent, saying it was "outdated tech" (see: [Why did Serpent die?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/why-did-serpent-die/21455#21455)).

Serpent's GitHub repository also has this to say:

> Being a low-level language, Serpent is NOT RECOMMENDED for building
>   applications unless you really really know what you're doing. The
>   creator recommends Solidity as a default choice, LLL if you want
>   close-to-the-metal optimizations, or Viper if you like its features
>   though it is still experimental.

So the recommendation would be to take a look at [Viper](https://github.com/ethereum/viper) instead.

Answer (score 0):

My os is `4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

my pip version is `pip 9.0.1 (python 2.7)`

I use commands below to install what you want.

```
sudo pip install ethereum-serpent
pip install pyepm
```